# WSDL Soap Web services integration with android

Tags: android, soap, service, wsdl

i have connection between wsdl soap services and android app 
but i have error can anybody help me please ?

This is Log Error :

```
10-28 10:19:02.489  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 404
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:237)
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Login$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(Login.java:62)
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Login$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(Login.java:46)
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-28 10:19:02.509  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-28 10:19:02.519  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-28 10:19:02.519  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-28 10:19:02.519  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-28 10:19:02.519  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-28 10:19:02.519  27277-27503/info.androidhive.slidingmenu W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my connection :

```
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Name_Space, Method);
                //bodyOut is the body object to be sent out with this envelope
                envelope.bodyOut = request;
                HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                try {
                    transport.call(Name_Space +"/"+Method, envelope);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //bodyIn is the body object received with this envelope
                if (envelope.bodyIn != null) {
                    //getProperty() Returns a specific property at a certain index.
                    SoapPrimitive resultSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getProperty(0);
                    resp=resultSOAP.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
            }
            return resp;
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not proper- but still check your url it should be like-

```
http://myurl.com/Service.svc/Service.svc
```

Comment: this's my Url : http://192.168.1.103:8101/DynamicsAx/Services/SolvaitESSServicesGroup

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "your soapAction"; //http://tempuri.org/ITurnoverService/GetTurnover
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "your method"; // like GetTurnover
private static final String SERVICE = "your service"; // like TurnoverService.svc
private static final String NAMESPACE = "your namespace"; // like http://tempuri.org/
```

Then apply these:

```
        String URL = "your url"; // like www.example.com/something/TurnoverService.svc

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("username", arg0[0]); // property add
        request.addProperty("password", arg0[1]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        httpTransport.debug = true;
        try {
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //send request

        Object  result = null;

        try {
            result = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
            response = String.valueOf(result);
        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```